# how do i get the the frame count when playing a video (xx:xx:xx,000)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

i'm playing a video via jquery and html and i need to determine the last values on a standard video timecode format (hours:minutes:seconds,framecount).

i'm just using a standard `<video>` tag in the html and calling it in jquery with 
`var video = $('#video');`

i also have this function that gets the currentTime of the video when it's played, but not the framecount.

```
    video.on('timeupdate', function() {
        var currentPos = video[0].currentTime;
        $('.current').text(currentPos); 
        console.log(currentPos);
    }
```

how can i use this to get the framecount?

Comment: Currently there's no realiable way to get the framecount. There are webkit and mozilla specific properties that come close, but again, not very reliable or cross browser. Here's a quick example using webkit -> https://jsfiddle.net/ym75vb5L/

Comment: i have the current time of the video and also the framerate, can I use that to figure out what frame we're on?